# How do I change the default cloud function open telemetry exporter?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

By default, cloud functions emit a span that's visible in Cloud Trace. If the function cis called with opentelemetry headers, that remote trace is propagated as expected.

If I add additional open telemetry instrumentation to my function and use the cloud trace exporter, everything works as expected.  If I change the exporter, my manually instrumented spans are sent to the new exporter but the default spans still go to cloud trace leaving gaps in my traces.

It appears that cloud functions have their own exporter that isn't configurable using the open telemetry environment variables.

Has anyone had luck rerouting the default spans or bypassing them in some way?

Comment: You could create, customize and change some options of the span. Please refer to this link for more information. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/trace/4.2.1/interfaces/SpanOptions.html